# stop form submitting in a function - jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

The codes posted might be not consistent because I am continuing someone's work and trying not to make too much changes if possible.
Anyways, there's this form which has inputs for others to input values.
upon submitting, if the input field is empty an alert will pop up and should stop the form from submitting.

I have tried using both `return false;` and `event.preventDefault();` inside the if input field is empty but the form still submits.

trying to cut this short because the script is hell lots

just a simple form

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" name="ordering" id="ordering" onsubmit="addDesc();">
    <button type="submit" class="add-to-cart" alt='Add this product to your shopping cart now.'>Add to Cart <span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></button>
  </form>
```

the function

```
function addDesc(desc){
// some variables to be passed when form submits
// an $.each function to loop through something
    //inside the loop it'll push input values into an array called checkEmpty
  if(jQuery.inArray("", checkEmpty) !== -1){
    alert('Please Do not leave any input fields empty.');
    return false;
  }else{
   //some outputs        
  }
}
```

`return false` is the first I tried but form still submitted.
I even tried something like

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', addDesc(event));
```

and inside addDesc() instead of `return false` I used `event.preventDefault()`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple. Just add a `return` before calling the function onsubmit:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" name="ordering" id="ordering" onsubmit="return addDesc();">
```

Should do the trick (returning `true` or `false` will send the form or prevent the submission).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/30/)**.

**HTML :**

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" name="ordering" id="ordering">
     <button type="submit" class="add-to-cart" alt='Add this product to your shopping cart now.'>Add to Cart <span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span></button>
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
$( "#ordering" ).submit(function( event ) {
    if(jQuery.inArray('', checkEmpty) !== -1){
         alert('Please Do not leave any input fields empty.');
         event.preventDefault();
    }else{
         alert('submiting');
    }
});
```

You're using JQuery so you don't have to use inline `onsubmit`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `addDesc` at the time of binding it, so the return value of that function is used.

Try this

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', addDesc);
```

or

```
onsubmit="addDesc"
```

Comment: I think just adding "return" before the call would work too.

Comment: form still submits and the alert didn't even alert too O.o

Answer (score 0):

change the button type as 'button" instead of 'submit'.And then you can call the function in the event of the button click.